Why is NSAttributedString formatting html list <ol><li> incorrectly
I'm upgrading my project to Xcode 16. When using the following function, it renders correctly with Xcode 15 but it is not on Xcode 16.
// The label created with `attributedText`.
let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText = self.init(html: "<ol><li>1th item</li><li>2th item</li><li>3rd item</li></ol>")
// The convenience function to init html `NSAttributedString` with a string instead of data.
extension NSAttributedString {
    public convenience init(html: String) {
        guard let encodedData = html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16) else {
            print("Unable to encode html string to data")
            self.init(string: html)
            return
        }
        assert(Thread.isMainThread, "The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread!")
        do {
            try self.init(
                data: encodedData,
                options: [
                    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf16.rawValue,
                ],
                documentAttributes: nil
            )
        } catch {
            print("Initialising NSAttributedString with html failed \(error)")
            self.init()
        }
    }
}

Does someone face this same issue?
I did expect the numbers of the list (expected result) items are rendered when using a `NSAttributedString` based on `html`. But with Xcode 16 it does not work. It is not showing the list points. (actual result)

Why are you using utf16 encoding?

I am having the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

I discovered that it was an iOS18 specific issue. Here is how I fixed it on my end:
var attributedOptions: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [:]

if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 18.0, *) {
  attributedOptions = [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,
    .textKit1ListMarkerFormatDocumentOption: true
  ]
} else {
  attributedOptions = [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,
  ]
}

Hope it helps!

Does this work for you?
When I apply this option, my app crashes at launch with a dyld crash when running my app on iOS 17.x or below.
dyld[20681]: Symbol not found: _NSTextKit1ListMarkerFormatDocumentOption

Use a text view instead of a label. Result:

The reason for the difference has to do with the fact that the numbering is not part of the text itself; it is a paragraph style, namely a text list, and has to be interpreted by TextKit. A text view has a more complete rendering of TextKit information than a label. You can easily make a text view that looks and behaves just like a label (e.g. not editable).

I filed a radar with Apple: https://openradar.appspot.com/FB15489218
If we have to use a text view instead of the label, which property of it must we use?
(attributedText won't do it because the problem is happening during conversion of HTML to NSAttributedString).

I don't see what you mean. My screen shot demonstrates that text view alternative works fine. The problem does not happen during conversion; it happens during presentation of the attributed text to the viewer, i.e. a text view knows how to present it in the way you expect, a label does not.

The radar I opened is specifically about the actual conversion going wrong. In other words, the content of NSAttributedString is wrong. I have a code example in the radar.

Well, we don't agree.
